# Salesforce Community (Napili Template) - Visualforce Page component not available

Tags: visualforce, napili, lightning-community

I've created a customer service community and trying to add a VF page to the record detail page, but I don't have an option to add the VF page. Am I missing anything? Under Content, there is supposed to be a Visualforce page component which can be drag and dropped but it's not available as shown below. The problem is in the community I created in Sandbox, but in developer edition it's fine.I'm following this documentation Using VF in Napili Templates [image][image]

Comment: Do you have My Domain enabled in either org?

Comment: Yeah, I've my domain enabled in both the orgs.. @dsharrison

Comment: Do you have the tickbox for the 'Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages' ticked on the VF page?

Answer (score 1):

After opening a case, Salesforce told me they need to enable the feature "Enable VisualForce Support in Communities from off to on" on your sandbox.